# How to access AWS Elasticsearch from Node JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-iam

I have my nodejs lambda trying to index data into ES, but it's failing because of this error:

> 2018-01-15T23:39:09.578Z   (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 131): Authorization Exception ::
>
> User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost on resource: ****

I have applied AmazonESFullAccess policy to the Lambda function role.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. Code was missing 'connectionClass' and 'amazonES' parameters.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var connectionClass = require('http-aws-es');
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client({  
    host: ***,
    log: 'error',
    connectionClass: connectionClass,
    amazonES: {
      credentials: new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS')
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution worked for me but I had to set the default region on the AWS object. `AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";`

https://github.com/TheDeveloper/http-aws-es/issues/44

Comment: I was getting the same error before `User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost`. But after adding this, I am getting `No Living connections`. What might be going wrong?